# Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration

Tags: facebook

I've been testing my app using my company's domain (which has ssl installed) and works like a charm.

now, I want this app to have its own domain, server and SSL certificate. I purchased a Godaddy SSL certificate(Standard (Turbo) SSL) and asked my hosting to install it, which they did and seems to be working ok...

now when I change the Facebook App settings to my new server, it just fails to load, and the console just outputs *"Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains. "*

Im completely lost on what to do... the settings are like this

Im loading FB using the facebook-actionscript-api 1.8.1

Namespace: myfbapp

App domains: myfbapp.com www.myfbapp.com

Sandbox: disabled

Canvas URL:  http://www.myfbapp.com

Secure c url: https://www.myfbapp.com

Answer (score 0):

needed to get a dedicated IP for my game and attach the SSL to it